# JPA, How insert new entities with relation ManyToMany?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I try:(look at code), but it does not work.

```
List<User> users = query.getResultList();

if (users.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("tworzę konto admina");
    User admin = new User();
    admin.set(...)

    Role role = new Role();
    role.setName("Develop");
    role.set...
    // the first method dont work
    admin.getRoles().add(role); /// but admin.getRoles() IS Null!!! (I get nullPointerExeption)


    // the second method dont work too
    // List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
    //roles.add(role);
    //admin.setRoles(roles);


    entityManager.persist(role);
    entityManager.persist(admin);
}
```

User class:

```
public class User {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "role_has_user",
            joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
            },
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
            }
    )
}
```

In second method I get:

---

```
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'rw.SEQUENCE' doesn't exist
Error Code: 1146
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)...
```

Comment: Can you show us full `User` class? What is your `eclipselink.ddl-generation` property value?

Comment: Acording to the exception trace, the issue has nothing to do with ManyToMany relationship. You may have set one of the fields of User to be generated, and yet you have not specified in your persistence.xml tables to be generated. Hence, there is no table called SEQUENCE, which can be used to generate one of your generated Ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create new list in User.

```
public User() {
    roles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your entities cannot be persisted because your JPA provider cannot generate Ids for them. You probably used a `@GeneratedValue` annotation but not created table `SEQUENCE` on the underlying database. Do you use schema generation? If no, than create appropriate table with `SEQ_COUNT` `SEQ_NAME` columns.